# Condition in xpath with absolute path

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to use an absolute path and add conditions to my XPath 1.0

```
<School>
<Category group = "red">
    <Teacher name = "john" Status = "Absent" />
    </Teacher>
</Category>
    <Category group = "Green">
    <Teacher name = "Smith" Status = "Present" />
</Category>
```

What i wish to achieve is :

```
if 
    /School/Category[@group = "Red"]/@Status = "Present"
then 
    /School/Category[@group = "Red"]/teacher/@name 
else
    /School/Category[@group = "Green"]/teacher/@name
```

Comment: Post the expected output given that sample XML as input

Comment: Ouput should be : Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath 1.0, you can do this way :

```
/School/Category[@group = 'red']/Teacher[@Status = 'Present']/@name 
    | 
/School[
    not(
        Category[@group = 'red']/Teacher[@Status = 'Present']
    )
]/Category[@group = 'Green']/Teacher/@name
```

The XPath part before the union operator (`|`) represent the following logic :

```
if 
    /School/Category[@group = "Red"]/@Status = "Present"
then 
    /School/Category[@group = "Red"]/teacher/@name
```

... and the rest represent the following logic :

```
if not
    (/School/Category[@group = "Red"]/@Status = "Present")
then 
    /School/Category[@group = "Green"]/teacher/@name
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9b97e2519d0752856eb142d826520022)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Smith
```

Comment: Thanks @har07. Been looking everywhere for this Xpath.